# Error while loading Youtube Video URL in Sencha touch Android App

Tags: html, cordova, youtube, sencha-touch-2

I have been facing this error on my sencha touch app using phonegap for android:

I have a youtube url linked to an iframe which loads the video and plays it. But when I am on slow networks, I get and alert saying "Could not load URL: http://www.youtube.com/embed/xyz..autoplay=0". When I click on OK in alert window, the app crashes.

I googled the issue and found that this could be the issue in the file : "MyPhonegapActivity.java", with the property : "**super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue",60000);**".

Following is the console log for the error:

"**CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-6 Description=Couldn't connect to the server. URL=http://www.youtube.com/embed/......!?fs=1&hl=en_US&rel=0&autoplay=0**"

I tried increasing the timeout value, but it did not help much.

Also, I want to mention that this issue comes in **7" samsung galaxy tab2**, but doesn't come in **google nexus 7**(even in slow networks). I figured out that nexus might ignore the timeout errors, and keeps trying to load the url. The app doesn't crash since it doesn't show the alert for timeout, it just shows the url on video window.

But I am not able to figure out the issue with samsung device. Any help would be appreciated, even anyway i could prevent the app from creashing. Thanks in advance.